# PERL - Remove certain data form array after a symbol

Tags: arrays, perl

my code looks like this

```
foreach ($id->{deleteids}) {
            my @separated = split('_', $_);
            push @rids, $separated[0];

        }
```

on using Data::Dumper on $id->{deleteids} i get this

```
 $VAR1 = [
          '43-173739_cdfvgbvvd',
          '43-173738_sddsvfdvfd',
          '43-173737_sfvdfvdfvdf',
          '43-173736_svdvdfvdfvdfvfdvfd'
        ];
```

My expected output of @rids that i want

```
  $VAR1 = [
          '43-173739',
          '43-173738',
          '43-173737',
          '43-173736'
        ];
```

but on using Data::Dumper on @rids i always get

```
$VAR1 = 'ARRAY(0x3210010)';
```

Comment: "_on using Data::Dumper on $id->{deleteids}_"   -- you mean using it on `@rids`?

Comment: i had modified the question i hope it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array references have different way to be called with, And as Zdim pointed you need to use a reference `\@rids` to dump array using Dumper

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;


my $id = { # creating a similar array like yours in a hash ref
  deleteids => [
           '43-173739_cdfvgbvvd',
           '43-173738_sddsvfdvfd',
           '43-173737_sfvdfvdfvdf',
           '43-173736_svdvdfvdfvdfvfdvfd'
         ]
};

print Dumper($id->{deleteids});
my @rids;

foreach (@{$id->{deleteids}}) { # correct way to use array ref
            my @separated = split('_', $_);
            push @rids, $separated[0];
}

print Dumper(\@rids); # how to dump array using Dumper
```

Output:

```
# $id hash ref
$VAR1 = [
          '43-173739_cdfvgbvvd',
          '43-173738_sddsvfdvfd',
          '43-173737_sfvdfvdfvdf',
          '43-173736_svdvdfvdfvdfvfdvfd'
        ];
# @rids
$VAR1 = [
          '43-173739',
          '43-173738',
          '43-173737',
          '43-173736'
        ];
```

Comment: The answer doesn't explain what the problem was. I recommend adding the following *The code you posted iterates over only one scalar, the reference to the array. This is what is being passed split instead of the elements of the array. The following shows how to iterate over the elements of the referenced array:*

Answer (score 0):

Following piece of code should do what you expect (remove undesired part)

```
foreach ($id->{deleteids}) {
     s/_.*//;
     push @rids, $_;
}
```